# For each grouping in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, grouping

I am new to XSLT and just started learning it. I need to change a simple thing.

My input XML file is

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>GO Home</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1987</year>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
    <company>CBS Records</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1988</year>
</cd>
</catalog>`
```

and output should be
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <list>
       <singer artist="Bob Dylan">
          <song>Empire Burlesque</song>
       </singer>
       <singer artist="Bonnie Tyler">
          <song>GO Home</song>
          <song>Hide you heart</song>
       </singer>
    </list>`

My XSL is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="list">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="catalog"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="catalog">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="cd" group-by="artist">
        <xsl:element name="singer">
            <xsl:attribute name="artist">
                <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="artist">
    <xsl:element name="song">
        <xsl:value-of select="../title"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

I seem to have problem with grouping and can't fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using an XSLT 2.0 processor? Note that you can write result elements literally with e.g. `<list>..</list>` instead of `<xsl:element name="list">..</xsl:element>`. And try `xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/artist"/>` instead of `xsl:apply-templates select="artist"/>`.

Comment: Yes, I am using XSLT 2.0 and will try you suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I am using XSLT 2.0 and you suggestion worked and thank you.